# How to retrieve only one pushId

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here there is randomly generated pushId's for a particular challenge in which there UID for  both receiver and sender. I am generating this pushId from one Activity now I want to retrieve this pushId from some other class or fragment. I used `onChildAdded` like this to retrieve pushId so that I can fetch the data of particular user:

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Challenge");
                databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                        String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
```

While using this method it's giving me the pushId but the issue is it's retrieving all the pushId's present in the "Challenge" Node but what I want to retrieve only single pushId wrt challenge. Is there any way so that I can retrieve only one pushId not all like for challenge1 I only want 1st pushId and for challenge2 2nd pushId and so on. Please help me out.

[image]

Comment: You say `you want to retrieve only single pushId challenge` but according to what?

Comment: Like there are two UID's inside the particular pushId wrt to those UID's I want there pushId.

Comment: To understand better. If we take the first challenge as an example (`-LFq_...z4OE`) which has beneath it 2 uids. Are the values of this two ids needed? `2vxd...E2C2` and `zkQx...oPS2`?

Comment: No I want the pushId I mean first challenge Id (-LFq_...z4OE) for every challenge I need it's pushId.

Comment: Please be more clear. You want only a single pushed id, let say the first one `(-LFq_...z4OE`? Or you want all pushed ids `-LFq_...z4OE`, `-LFqa...NjWO` and so on?

Comment: I want only one pushId for a particular challenge. Right now the way I am retrieving pushId's with onChildAdded() but it's giving all the pushId's. so I want to know how can I retrieve only single pushId

Comment: You say: `I want only one pushId for a particular challenge` according to what? You want the first pushed id, the last? Which one?

Comment: here pushId represents the unique id for each challenge so it does'nt matters that it is first or last. The thing I want I just want to retrieve the single pushId in the Challenge node for each challenge so that I can go inside that pushId and fiddle with it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173753/discussion-between-divyank-vijayvergiya-and-alex-mamo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways in which you can achieve this. First one would be to store that pushed id once it is generated and use it later whenever is needed in your reference. So when adding a `Challange` object to the database use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference challangeRef = rootRef.child("Challange");
String key = challangeRef.push().getKey();
challangeRef.child(key).setValue(yourChallangeObject);
```

Once this `key` is generated, you can use it whenever you need it in your activity.

As @PeterHaddad also mentioned in his answer, antoher approach would be to use a `Query`. So you have to add a `fixed` property under each challange object so you can query the database according to it. I recommend you add the `id` of the user who has created the the challange. The query in this case should look like this:

```
Query query = challangeRef.orderByChild("uid").equalTo(uid).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(/* ... */);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I have little issues like In first approach what is yourChallengeObject here and how can I retrieve this key through challengobject in other activities and in another approach if I add the id of sender who has created the "Challenge" then how can receiver retrieve that key because uid of receiver is different how same query works for both sender and receiver so that I can retrieve the values of both sender and receiver.

Comment: If you are adding data to the database using a model class like `Challange yourChallangeObject = new Challange()`; then this is the object that you need to pass to the `setValue()` method. If you are using a map, then pass that map as an argument. If you need both uids of sender and receiver, then create another node in which you can store only this uids.

Comment: I have that node called match in which I am storing the uid's of both receiver and sender inside the challenge key which is `(-LFq_...z4OE)` but how that query   `Query query = challangeRef.orderByChild("uid").equalTo(uid).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(/* ... */);` works for both users simultaneously.

Comment: No, should work only for the user that you are creating the query. Let's say the creator of the challange is the sender then you need to query using the sender id `challangeRef.orderByChild("senderUid").equalTo(senderUid).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(/* ... */);`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the first pushid, then you need to use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` and a query example `orderByChild`:

```
 DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Challenge");

reference.orderByChild("timeChallengeMinute").equalTo("58").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
 @Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
   for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
        String keys=datas.getKey();
     }
  }
@Override
 public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
   }
 });
```

`addListenerForSingleValueEvent` will read data once, and when you use a query like `orderByChild` you will be able to get the related data. The above will retrieve the pushid `where timeChallengeMinute ="58"`

Comment: timeChallengeMinute is not a fixed value it's vary for every challenge so i can't do like this.

Comment: yes but this is the only way, you need to add another field example "key=1" and then do orderByChild("key").equalTo("1")

Comment: This solution is same as onChildAdded() method if I create another field key then this field should create inside  all the pushId's so the thing is it will give me all the pushId's when I will try to retrieve.

Comment: how will it give you all the pushid if you query it?If the first pushid has key=1 and the second pushid has key=2, how will it give you all the pushid after querying?

Comment: but how can I set different values for field "key" in different pushId's thats the thing according to my code I can only set the value of key once because these pushId's are generated randomly by button click. And this whole thing is dynamic I can't orderby them with one specific fixed value every time.

Comment: So you ended up implementing the concept that was written in this answer..

Comment: Yes approach is like this only.

Answer (score 0):

To do it just do this, first reference to Challenge, and then just iterate throught all the childrens inside that particular node, then just retrieve the key of each children with `getKey()`

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Challenge");
                databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

          String pushid = snapshot.getKey();


 }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```